# profinite completion of a ring of integers in a global field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, function-fields, profinite-groups

It is well known that the profinite completion of the integers, $\hat{\mathbb{Z}} = \varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is, by the Chinese remainder theorem, isomorphic to $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$.

I have two questions about this.  1) Is this ring isomorphism also topological?  and 2) does it generalize to the ring of integers in a global field?  Id est, if $\mathcal{O} \subset k$ is the ring of integers in a number field or global function field over a finite field, do we know that $\hat{\mathcal{O}}\cong \prod_\mathfrak{p} \mathcal{O}_\mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ varies over all (finite?) primes and $\mathcal{O}_\mathfrak{p}$ is the local completion with respect to $\mathfrak{p}$ ?

Since $\hat{\mathcal{O}} = \varprojlim \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{n}$ and since we have a unique factorisation of ideals into prime ideals, I feel like the CRT would give us this same result.  Is my intuition correct?

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct... what fuller answer, if any, would be useful?

Comment: A "yes" to a yes/no question is sufficient.  But the topological point is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly more discussion of various details could be warranted, depending on taste/interest, but the basic topological point is that those *finite* quotients $\mathfrak O/\mathfrak n$ have a unique locally compact Hausdorff topology, namely, the discrete topology. Projective limits of topological rings (with identities $1$ mapping to each other, for example) exist in a category of locally compact Hausdorff topological rings: the closed subset of the product defined by the transition maps in the limit.

Products and (projective) limits are both instances of "limit" in a somewhat larger sense, and "commute", so Sun-Ze's theorem (a.k.a. "Chinese Remainder Theorem") gives the indicated factorization.