# Is $\mathbb{Z}_p[\omega]$ profinite when $\omega$ is a primitive $p$-root of unity?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, profinite-groups

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the $p$-adic integers. We have that the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ applying the Eisenstein criterion (which is valid over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ when $p$ is the prime being used to prove irreducibility). So for $\omega$ a primitive $p$-th root of unity we have a ring extension $\mathbb{Z}_p[\omega]$ of degree $p-1$.

Is this ring also profinite? My attempt to prove it would be by considering extensions of the finite quotients $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial is equivalent to $(X-1)^{p-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[X]$, so this extension would be trivial.

Is this the right way to go? Maybe it is irreducible (or at least doesn't have a root) modulo $p^2$ or $p^k$ for some $k$, but I'm low on ideas on how to analyse that.

Another way to go would be if the topology on $\mathbb{Z}_p[\omega]$ is the product topology. Therefore, as it is the product of profinite spaces, it must be again profinite. I'm actually unsure if there is a canonical way of extending the topology of a topological ring $R$ to any of it's finite extensions other than the product topology, or if there is a canonical topology of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ that may not coincide with the product, so I don't know if this argument applies.

Comment: Related I guess: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383005/profinite-completion-of-a-ring-of-integers-in-a-global-field

Comment: The $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial is not $X^p-1$, you need to remove the rational root at $X = 1$. Moreover, the extension over $\mathbb F_p$ for either $(X-1)^p$ or the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial is not trivial, it's just ramified (i.e., it has a non-trivial nilradical). That's to be expected, since the extension you're considering is totally ramified. Anyways, you're right that the topology on the extension is the product topology. Additively it's just a free module over $\mathbb Z_p$ of rank $p-1$.

Comment: And no, the topology put on it in this way is not canonical, but the results are all homeomorphic. (They differ by a $\mathbb Z_p$-linear automorphism corresponding to different choices of additive bases)

Comment: @Andrew If fail to see why the extension over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is non-trivial given that the $p$-th cyclotomic $1 + X + \cdots + X^{p-1}$ factors completly as linear factors $(X-1)^{p-1}$. Now, killing $K[X]$ by a linear polynomial gives you something isomorphic to $K$ right? And thanks for the topological remark! Is there a reference I can look into?

Comment: @Henrique: the extension is $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x - 1)^{p-1}$. This is a fine *ring* extension. It happens not to be a field extension but that doesn't matter here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan apparently I'm using the wrong definition for the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial. Does the expression $(x^p-1)/(x-1)$ doesn't work for base field? Isn't the extension $p$-th cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ given precisely by killing $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ by the ideal generated by this polynomial?

Comment: OH now I see that $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(x-1)^{p-1}$ is **not** a field. Then, I'm not sure now how to define the $p$-th cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Well, you can define it as that ring. It’s not a field. But these quotients are perfectly adequate for answering your question about profiniteness.

Comment: As for a reference you could have a look at Cassels' Local Fields.

Comment: Take your profinite ring $R$, and show that any free $R$-module $M$ of finite rank is also profinite. You should be willing to express things in $M$ as $R$-linear combinations of the basis. First do the warmup exercise of proving the fact when $R=\projlim_nR/I_n$, where $\{I_n\}$ is a descending chain of ideals with $\bigcap_nI_n=(0)$.